# How to call a function in the backend without a click event in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a screen which does not have any button but a label that shows my system is active. Then I want to call the main of another python program (separate from kivy) whenever I arrive on that screen. I have tried on_enter() but failed.

I don't know how to really use on_enter() if one can guide me with working examples then that will be just fine for me.

I have merged all the screens through the main so the code will be a bit longer as I want to give you a clear picture of what I have achieved so far.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from Login.login import BackendWindow, MyScreenManager
from Register.register import RegisterWindow
from Activated_System.active_screen import ActiveWindow
from Result.result import ResultWindow

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):


    login_widget = BackendWindow()
    register_widget = RegisterWindow()
    active_widget = ActiveWindow()
    result_widget = ResultWindow()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.ids.scrn_login.add_widget(self.login_widget)
        self.ids.scrn_reg.add_widget(self.register_widget)
        self.ids.scrn_active.add_widget(self.active_widget)
        self.ids.scrn_result.add_widget(self.result_widget)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(Self):
        return MainWindow()

if __name__=='__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<MainWindow>:
    id: main_win

    ScreenManager:
        id: scrn_mngr_main

        Screen:
            id: scrn_login
            name: 'scrn_login'

        Screen:
            id: scrn_reg
            name: 'scrn_reg'


        Screen:
            id: scrn_active
            name: 'scrn_active'


        Screen:
            id: scrn_result
            name: 'scrn_result'
```

Above is the main code from where I am controlling the transfer of all the screen.

Below is the screen where I want to call the main of a separate python program and run it

active_screen.py

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('Activated_System/active.kv')

class ActiveWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)



class ActiveApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ActiveWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sa = ActiveApp()
    sa.run()
```

Apart from this, I am transferring control to another screen like this in the rest of the screens through a button click:

```
self.parent.parent.current = 'scrn_id'
```

Please let me know how can I achieve this I have tried some ways like calling the main of separate python program in the constructor but that calls the program even before I reach the active_screen page as I have made the objects in the main.py

I am still learning kivy so a detailed answer will be more useful.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]..

Comment: I have altered the code to be as minimal as possible, otherwise, the code will not work if I shorten it any more.@noEmbryo

Comment: A bunch of scripts are missing (`Login, Activated, Register`...) This is also impossible to execute.. Please read what a [mcve] is..